# XPath/Domdocument check for child by class name

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I am trying to find child nodes by a certain class name (divs with class name='foo') within a loop of DOMDocument nodes. If it exists it should set my foo value to 1:

My HTML $document looks like:

```
...
<div class="posts">Div Posts 1</div>
<div class="posts">Div Posts 2<div class="foo"></div></div>
<div class="posts">Div Posts 3</div>
<div class="posts">Div Posts 4<div class="foo"></div></div>
<div class="posts">Div Posts 5</div>
...
```

DOMDocument/Xpath ($document):

```
$html = array();
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTMLFile($url); // loads html from above
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($document);

$i=0;
foreach ($xpath->query(Parser::cssToXpath('.posts')) as $node) {
    $html['posts'][$i]['content'] = $node->nodeValue;  
    // check if child node with class name 'foo' exists => doesn't work :(
    $children = $node->getElementsByTagName('foo');
    if($children)
        $html['posts'][$i]['foo'] = '1';
    else
        $html['posts'][$i]['foo'] = '0';
    $i++;
}
```

Output:

```
[posts] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [content] => Div class Posts 1
                [foo] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [content] => Div class Posts 2
                [foo] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [content] => Div class Posts 3
                [foo] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [content] => Div class Posts 4
                [foo] => 1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [content] => Div class Posts 5
                [foo] => 1
            )

    )
```

getElementsByTagName() might not be the right method for that, but I tried different methods already and don't find the right one. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment

> Hm yes but still doesn't work unfortunately. Eventually I need to know which .posts div has the child element 'foo' because I need to analyze the content of that parent and also need to replace it later

to the previous answer your predicate is probably:

a) select div elements
b) with attribute class=posts
c) and with a child element div
d) which has attribute class=foo

as xpath expression:

a) //div
b) //div[ @class="posts" ]
c) //div[ @class="posts" and div ]
d) //div[ @class="posts" and div[ @class="foo" ] ]

e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml( getData() );
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);   

/*
use something like
    //div[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' post ')]
if the html element may have class="post lalala"
*/
foreach( $xpath->query('//div[@class="posts" and div[@class="foo"]]') as $post) {
    while ( $post->firstChild ) {
        $post->removeChild( $post->firstChild );
    }   
    $post->appendChild( $doc->createElement('span', 'The quick fox....') );
}
echo $doc->savehtml();


function getData() {
    return <<< eoh
<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
    <div class="posts">Div Posts 1</div>
    <div class="posts">Div Posts 2<div class="foo"></div></div>
    <div class="posts">Div Posts 3</div>
    <div class="posts">Div Posts 4<div class="foo"></div></div>
    <div class="posts">Div Posts 5</div>
</body></html>
eoh;
}
```

prints

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><title>...</title></head><body>
    <div class="posts">Div Posts 1</div>
    <div class="posts"><span>The quick fox....</span></div>
    <div class="posts">Div Posts 3</div>
    <div class="posts"><span>The quick fox....</span></div>
    <div class="posts">Div Posts 5</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: VolkerK thanks alot! It took me a while to get through, but it works liek a charme! :-) Many thanks!

Comment: Hi VolkerK, do you know how I can find out which position my the replaced element has. e.g. which nth.child() or eq() the element in the DOM tree has? Like (pseudo) $post->appendChild..(...'the quick fox...'); $post->GetNthChildorEqNr#() ... // would give me 2, and 4

Comment: Hi Volker, sorry this is a follow up. I wrote another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465095/find-index-position-of-a-domnode-xpath-child-element. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath to find all `div` elements with class `foo`

```
//div[@class = 'foo']
```

To be more specific, use this:

```
//div[@class = 'posts']/div[@class = 'foo']
```

Comment: Hi Kirill, thanks for you answer. But, I want to able to check if the 'foo' div exists within the parent node, not to only get "all" div elements with class foo. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Mike, So you can use 2nd query. It will return all `div` with class `foo` only if they are within `div` with class `posts.`

Comment: Hm yes but still doesn't work unfortunately. Eventually I need to know which .posts div has the child element 'foo' because I need to analyze the content of that parent and also need to replace it later with a jquery script $(".posts:eq(1) > .foo").html(). 2nd query would only give me all div classes named 'foo', not their position. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Mike, Maybe this XPath will help you: `//div[@class = 'posts'][div[@class = 'foo']]`. It selects only `div.posts` which contains `div.foo`.