# Find index position of a DomNode/Xpath Child Element

Tags: php, xpath, dom-node

I am using an xpath expression to determine a certain div-class in my DOM tree (thanks to VolkerK!).

```
foreach($xpath->query('//div[@class="posts" and div[@class="foo"]]') as $node)
    $html['content'] = $node->textContent;
    //$html['node-position'] = $node->position(); // (global) index position of the child 'foo'
}
```

Eventually I need to know which (global) index position my child 'foo' has, because I want to replace it with jQuery later: [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or nth-child().

Is there a way to do it?

I am following up on another Question of mine about selecting the right element ([XPath/Domdocument check for child by class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362165/xpath-domdocument-check-for-child-by-class-name/9363516#comment11970612_9363516)).

Thanks!

***UPDATE:***

I have found out that using:

```
$html['node-position'] = $node->getNodePath()
```

actually gives me the path and the element number in xpath syntax (/html/body/div[3]) of the parent node, but how can it for the child div 'foo'?

Comment: Are you sure you need nth-child? Or would adding a class to the element suffice? Then you could do something like e.g. `$('.replaceThis').each( function(e) { ... } );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The XPath way to find the "position" of a given element `x`** (where position is defined to mean the index of that element `x` in the sequence (in document order) of all `x` elements in the XML document) **is**:

```
count(preceding::x) + count(ancestor-or-self::x)
```

When this XPath expression is evaluating with the element `x` as the current node (initial context node), the so defined "position" is produced.

**XSLT - based verification**:

Let's have this XML document:

```
<t>
    <d/>
    <emp/>
    <d>
        <emp/>
        <emp/>
        <emp/>
    </d>
    <d/>
</t>
```

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="v3rdEmp" select="/*/d/emp[2]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "count($v3rdEmp/preceding::emp)
   +
    count($v3rdEmp/ancestor-or-self::emp) "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

evaluates the above XPath expression using the 3rd `emp` element in the document as the initial context node. The `x` in the expression is now substituted by our wanted element name -- `emp`. Then the result from the expression evaluation is output -- we see that this is the wanted, correct result:

```
3
```

Comment: Cool thanks! Actually found a solution with making an array of all elements and compare the path afterwards, but I'll check that. +1 and accepted.

Comment: @Mike: Why waste memory (twice) for all elements, and writing non-portable code, when XPath gives this to us in one simple expression?

Answer (score 0):

Foreach [supports](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) syntax `$traversable as $key => $item`, therefore when you use:

```
foreach($xpath->query('//div[@class="posts" and div[@class="foo"]]') as $key => $node)
    $html['content'] = $node->textContent;
    $html['node-position'] = $key;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vyktor, Thanks! But the problem is that I have multiple 'foo' elements, some of them are not within 'posts' so I really would love to have a solution for the domnode... Sorry I didn't point that out.